# How to transition from vc1.view to vc2.view in iOS, without any navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uiview, transition

I have vc1.view covering the whole screen, and I want to be able to dim vc1.view, and have vc2.view zoom into the whole screen.

I don't have any navigation controller in the app, so what's the best practice to achieve my goal? The solution I'm thinking of is:

- Add both vc1.view and vc2.view into a common container view
- Use [UIView transitionFromView:vc1.view toView:vc2.view ......]

I dislike the idea of having to add views of different vc into a common container view. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: call [vc1 presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil]; from vc1

Comment: Thanks for the info. presentViewController:animated:completion: will provide the basic transition. What if I want to make the transition fancier, like dissolve or flip? I tried adding both to a common container, works fine, just feels weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present from vc1 to vc2 without a navigation controller, use

```
[vc1 presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To change the presenting style, Apple provides a few. You just need to set it before calling the above code:

```
vc2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Here is the list:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use transitionFromView:toView:... without adding the new view to a common container, because that transition method takes care of adding the view. The following worked for me. The code is in the view controller whose view is the "from view". I'm using a cross fade here, but you could change that to any of the other available methods:

```
-(void)switchViews:(id)sender {
    UIWindow *win = self.view.window;
    YellowController *yellow = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Yellow"];
    yellow.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:yellow.view duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        win.rootViewController = yellow;
    }];
}
```

However, to do a custom transition, you do have to add the new view as a subview of whatever view the "from view" is in (I think). In this example, that is the window's view. This code grows the new view from the center of the old one, while that one fades out. At the end of the transition, the view controller is switched to the one that owns the new view (yellow in this case)

After Edit: I changed this method to use a CGAffineTransform (thanks to jrturton for that suggestion made in an answer to my question):

```
-(void)switchViews3:(id)sender {
    UIWindow *win = self.view.window;
    YellowController *yellow = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Yellow"];
    yellow.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    yellow.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.1, .1);
    [win addSubview:yellow.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
        yellow.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.alpha = 0;
    }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                     win.rootViewController = yellow;
                 }];
```

}